# How can I see which Economy classes (Q,O,P,N, etc) while booking in Momondo?

Tags: flight-search-engines

The booking screen is like this:

[image]

I can't see anywhere that indicates the booking class in Momondo while booking.

Comment: You should see it on the actual booking site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see it on Momondo, because you don't book it with momondo. If you click through to the actual booking site, you should be able to see it. Example:

[image: Example Momondo search]

Now, if I click through to one of the booking sites:

[image: Booking site]

You'll see the exact booking class there.

Comment: Does this hold true for **all** booking sites??